# how to disable one header among of multiple headers in jQuery table sorter

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter

I've used [this table sorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Now, I've to use multiple headers inside the `<thead>`. I want only one row stay active for sorting. Without that row, I want other rows of header being disabled for sorting. How can I make this? [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/8cx76gu9/) Is there any way disabling one header by css class like this?

```
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th class="sorter-false">Info</th> 
    <th class="sorter-false">Info</th> 
    <th class="sorter-false">Info</th> 
    <th class="sorter-false" colspan="2">Text</th> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the original tablesorter... the class `sorter-false` only works on my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

Comment: I've already used the original and got the solution too. But, it seems that your modified version is better than original. I'll use that if I need again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter to your table sorter plugin:

```
 $("#myTable").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    selectorHeaders: '.sorter-true'
});
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/dcwrh9Lx/1/

Answer (score 1):

[From their documentation:](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration)

> ...to disable sorting on the first two columns of a table:
>   `headers: { 0: { sorter: false}, 1: {sorter: false} }`

You also have to rows of  which appear to be screwing it up a bit.. I updated your fiddle here, which for example excludes the first 2 from sorting: http://jsfiddle.net/8cx76gu9/1/

Change the 0 and 1 to whatever index of the column you'd like to change